# Is it possible to scan a website for repeated images?

Tags: security, web

Is it possible to determine how many times a website is using an image (specifically one that is hosted on the domain), and on what pages? Is there a command line tool, for example, that scans every page's source for the specific URL of the image and then returns the location of that page?

Comment: What about cases like `foo.png`, `images/foo.png`, `../images/foo.png` and `./images/foo.png` all of which refer to the same file?

Comment: From a pragmatic point of view, it might be easier to run a crawler over the site, throw what it downloads away, and see if your image is requested more than once, and with what referer headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is, yes, it is possible to do all those things but, no, there is no command line tool to do that task specifically. You could create a script or program to do what you describe but some effort would need to be made to do that.

Comment: Writing a script is not a problem. Do you know the tools available? I started by downloading the entire site, and running grep to check the html files for the existence of the source, which worked, but was painfully slow.

Comment: @ShaunGillies I would probably use Python or Perl for this task.